# Drupal Multi-Site Setup (Different Contet - Shared Nodes)

Tags: 7, nodes, multi-sites

I have a complex setup here, and I don't know how to do it in Drupal.

Site1 (Master) - MasterDB and SharedDB
Site2 (Sub-Site) - DB2 and SharedDB
Site3 (Sub-Site) - DB3 and SharedDB
SiteN (Sub-Site) - DB3 and SharedDB

SharedDV currently only has users / sessions for single sign-on

Okay, so I want to be able to create a content type of "Reports" that exists in all the sites. And I when I add a new report, I want it to show up on all sub-sites. However, I want the sub-sites to be able to add there own reports that don't effect other sub-sites or master.

Basically, I want a way to have Master to be able to control the default of for the all the sub-sites, but then allow the sub-sites to add to that if they want.

Another example, lets say I create a content type "Billing" or "Payments"... I want to be able to define that for all the sites, but I don't want any site to be able to see each others payments.

Another way to think of it is, Use Shared DB plus subsite DB.

All the sites are going to be VERY close to the same, just different theme mainly. and there own content. I just don't want to have to make a change 100 times because I change the name of a content-type or add a new field to a content type or setup a new report 100 times that is the same...

Thanks!

Comment: I think Drupal Domain Access might be my answer. http://drupal.org/project/domain

Comment: you should write that up as an answer and expand on it a bit.